# HTTP/2 stream 0 was not closed cleanly at 1028MB

Tags: nginx, curl, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, kong

I have a web server that returns a large amount of JSON (over 1GB)
When I `curl` it directly, it works fine.

However, when I put it behind a Kubernetes ingress (Kong which is based of nginx), the connection always gets cut off at 1028M

[image]

Any ideas how I can approach this?

Comment: Have you seen this thread: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/4679?

Comment: @JakubSiemaszko yes, but it doesn't describe my problem. see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with this setting: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_max_temp_file_size

Basically, slow clients caused the server to buffer response in a temporary file in nginx. Once file reached its size limit, nginx cut the connection.

I'm still not 100% why nginx cut the connection (maybe upstream server timed out), but increasing that value solved my problem